# Load EF relationship while performing joins

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have entity framework setup and I have the following relationships setup:

- AdListing (AdListingID, Title, Details)
- AdListingLocation ( An AdListing can have multiple locations: AdListingID, LocationID)
- Location (LocationID, Country, City)

In EF I would like to return all AdListings where the City is "New York"

Keep in mind I would also like to load the AdListingLocation relationship (along with some others). In another post I learned I am not allowed to do manual joins if I am using .Include. How can I accomplish both?

```
var results = (from a in db.AdListings.Include("AdListingPhotos").Include("AdListingLocations")
               where a.AdListingLocations.Location.City = "New York"
               select a).ToList();
```

Comment: What do you mean by manual join? where a.AdListingLocations.Location.City == "New York" isn't really a manual join. The query will create a join but you're just navigating the relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var results = from a in db.AdListings
              where a.AdListingLocations.Location.City == "New York"
              select a;

return results
       .Include(a => a.AdListingPhotos)
       .Include(a => a.AdListingLocations)
       .ToList();
```

To get the lambda syntax on Include just put this line:

```
 using System.Data.Entity;
```

Comment: When i tried your suggestion I get the error:

'System.Linq.IQueryable<Scribe.Model.AdListing>' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Scribe.Model.AdListing>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Did you add the using System.Data.Entity?

Comment: Yep I included the using statement you specified, I checked the version of System.Data.Entity and its using version "4.0.0.0" and runtime version "v4.0.30319" do you think I need a later version?

Comment: It might have been added in 4.1. You can change the code to use the string version instead. I like the lambda syntax because it will fail at compile time if you specify an invalid relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving your `.Include()` calls after your query?

```
var results = (from a in db.AdListings
           where a.AdListingLocations.Location.City = "New York"
           select a).Include("AdListingPhotos").Include("AdListingLocations").ToList();
```

You should now be able to perform a join in your query.

I haven't tested this, so it might not work as expected.